# How to make my application add column to a PostgreSQL view

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2, ddl

I need to find a way for my application to add a column to a PostgreSQL view. This needs to be done dinamically so I cannot hardcode my view, instead I need to get it's actual code through some crazy select or something like that.

I thought about doing this by calling a PostgreSQL procedure that gets the view's create script, drop it and then recreate it with the new column. Problem is, I don't know how to get the view's create script.

How can I do that or is there another way to accomplish it?

My application uses PHP with Zend Framework 2 and I'm using Postgres database.

Edit 1: I solved my problem by storing the original CREATE VIEW script into a variable, than I loop into the aditional columns adding them to the script.

Comment: FWIW, what you're trying to do sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I wouldn't categorize it as XY problem because I did explain the context and asked for another solution if possible, but thanks, glad to know that exists.

Comment: FYI, there is a [`pg_get_viewdef()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html), which returns the underlying `SELECT` statement only (without the `CREATE  VIEW <name>` part). But honestly, your goal sounds like a really bad concept to me.

Comment: @pozs: pg_get_viewdef() is a family of functions, some of which are deprecated. This syntax should be good: `select pg_get_viewdef(to_regclass('my_view_name'));`.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior: The context and other solutions aren't important here. "My application needs to dynamically modify a view" looks like the "Y" part of an XY problem. "Dynamically modify a view" isn't an application requirement. You seem to *think* you need to dynamically modify a view to solve some other problem. That's why we're skeptical, and why this sounds like a bad idea to us.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' yes, I thought about the `oid` (`regclass`) parametered variant too. The `text` one is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't store a view's "actual code". That is, PostgreSQL doesn't store the `create view` statement.

You can use `create or replace view ...` to add columns at the end. But you either have to already have the columns and their order, or you have to lookup all that information in the [information_schema views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) or in the [PostgreSQL system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html).

To replace a view, you have to be the owner, or you have to be a member of the owning role.

---

As pozs points out, there is a group of pg_get_viewdef() functions. They don't return the original `create view` statement, but I'm pretty confident that the critical information--the names and ordering of the columns--will let you add columns "at the end".

This is an actual `create view...` statement I wrote to run against my calendar table.

```
create view weekdays as 
select cal_date, day_of_week
from calendar
where day_of_week in ('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri');
```

Here's how I used pg_get_viewdef().

```
select pg_get_viewdef(to_regclass('weekdays'));
```

And here's what it returned.

```
SELECT calendar.cal_date,
    calendar.day_of_week
   FROM calendar
  WHERE (calendar.day_of_week = ANY (ARRAY['Mon'::bpchar, 'Tue'::bpchar, 'Wed'::bpchar, 'Thu'::bpchar, 'Fri'::bpchar]));
```